# Unable to figure out the correct data structure and correct approach in this scenario of parsing text

Tags: java, multithreading, parsing, architecture, executor

I am working on a text document parsing application.

The design of the document is as shown in the figure [image: figure]

Here is how the parsing is being done:

1. Document contains an ArrayList of pages
   .
2. Each page has a **`Map<float, List<Character>>`**

the `float` value contains the yaxis value of a character location and hence a `key` and Character contains other informations.

Parsing is done character by character via third party library.  Please add comments if more information is required.

Now while parsing I have created two ExecutorService thread pools, one for pages and one for populating map.

I initially create a Document and pass each page to the `page parser` as a runnable to `ExecutorService`. Which in turn passes an `empty map` to text parser.

Text parser checks if the `map` has a key value
   if yes it adds the character to the list or a new list what ever is necessary.

Problem here is that this task can be done concurrently for all pages to speed up execution. But I am unable to do with this data structure as all threads stuck in between if parsed normally and if done in a synchronized fashion using `Collections.synchronizedMap` , takes a lot of time.

Also, I am maintaining two different lists of Future objects to check if the threads finished.

Kindly provide valuable suggestions for improvements and concurrent execution to speed up the execution.

Comment: Start doing it in a single thread, in the simplest possible way, and see if it's fast enough. Then if not, measure what takes time, and try optimizing. Doing plenty of things concurrently is not a magical way of doing things faster. It has inherent costs due to context switching, synchronization, added complexity, etc.

Comment: Nizet I agree but see when you are parsing a document of around 5k pages I have to keep on waiting for over a minute. Single thread for sure is not a solution for this. There are further computations to be done once maps are ready

Comment: Then try adopting a simple work division strategy. You have 5000 pages, 4 CPU cores. So create 4 threads, each parsing 1250 pages, and assemble the result once they're all done.

Comment: @JB Nizet I will try this approach and will get back to you in few hours. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If each page has its own `Map<float, List<Character>>`, then never have more than one thread processing a single page - then you won't need to synchronize access to the `Map` or use a concurrent `Map` implementation.  You can statically partition the pages among your workers as JB Nizet suggests in the comments; another option would be to place all pages in a [ConcurrentLinkedQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedQueue.html) and have the workers `poll` the queue for pages to parse, terminating when the queue is empty (`poll` returns `null`).  Either way, you'll only need one `ExecutorService`, since each worker is responsible for both parsing and map population.